# Can I force 'Quick Save' to use a new file each time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

Console scripts, mods, or voodoo is acceptable as an answer.

Comment: Well, first you're going to need a voodoo doll shaped like your F5 key...

Comment: I would think you could employ something like my perennial solution, AutoHotKey, to intercept the F5, make a copy of your old quicksave, and then pass the quicksave action to Skyrim.  I don't own the game though, so I'd be a bad one to write such a script, as I can't test it. :)

Comment: I could macro the console command "~", then "save" + something unique.  If there was a console command to get the current time or a guid this would work.

Comment: ps: perennial?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perennial_(disambiguation)  help me out here.

Comment: "ongoing activity" - I suggest autohotkey frequently :)

Comment: @Killith: Check [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perennial) instead for a simple adjective. Definition #5 in particular applies here.

Comment: thanks for the word lesson gents.  I used to be much better at word comprehension, then I took an arrow in the knee.

Comment: You might want to check out [Auto-save and time](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/13239/?) it allows custom auto-save triggers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, **back up your save games** and then you can try using AutoHotKey to create quicksave backups.  The way I've set up AHK, it should refuse to overwrite files, but I wouldn't trust your only copy of your Skyrim saves to this, as it's untested.  Again, I *provide no warranty, use at your own risk.*

Try the following, using AutoHotKey:

```
F5::
OldQuickSave := "C:\myquicksave.sav"
FileGetTime, qstime, %OldQuickSave%
BackupFileName := "C:\backup saves\myquicksave_" . qstime . ".sav"
FileCopy, %OldQuickSave%, %BackupFileName%
SendPlay {F5}
return
```

Edit the paths as needed for the location of the quicksave file and where you want the backups to go.  If you put the "BackupFileName" location as the save directory, then it will probably show up in your list of saved games, and they'll be named with the date/time you quicksaved previously.

Once you've edited it to your liking, you'll have to put this in a file with the extension ".ahk" and double click.

I don't have Skyrim, so I can't test this out personally.  Hopefully it at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: An AHK Solution that doesn't require mucking with the existing save files, and thus no backups, might be one that simply macros the typing of the console command `save FILENAME`. Probably much safer, so long as AHK can be set up to generate those filenames, (say, based on timestamp)

Comment: You could probably take the FileGetTime line to get the current timestamp, and then pull the console down and enter the save command.  There's actually less risk the way I specified, since the game should still be quicksaving.  The worst that can happen is that you overwrite the quicksave instead of creating a new one.  I just put that disclaimer in just in case something goes pear shaped.

Comment: This worked, with a little fiddling.  If someone has the same issue and can't figure it out leave a comment and I'll try to help.  Thanks!

Comment: What was the fiddling?  I think you should be able to at least suggest an edit to my post if there's something that's not 100% with it.  That way other people looking will get the benefit of your efforts as well as mine :)

Answer (score 3):

The quicksave functionality in the game engine really isn't suited to making multiple saves, for a number of reasons having to do with loading optimisations and bugs related to that. Trying to make multiple *actual* quicksaves is a recipe for savegame corruption and crashes.

What you want is a "full" save, which makes a new save each time automatically, with the one-button ease of a quicksave. All you need is a way to trigger a full save with a button, and you've got a effective "quick save" button that cuts out the one-save-only and bugs of the game's built-in quick save.

There are a number of ways to do this. The easiest is to install a mod that uses SKSE to trigger the save command, such as [Save Hot Key ArchMod](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/17329). Any of a number of mods should do though, so that's just one to get you started. If you want to shop around, search the [Skyrim Nexus](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/) for `hot key` or `hotkey` and look for the mods that offer save-button functionality.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I cannot find any information on the web about this, and (at least looking at the file size and extensions), the quicksaves look a lot like regular saves.

Comment: Basically I had an idea of making a little program that monitors the savegame folder and as soon as the quicksave file is overwritten, it makes a copy of it. It would keep, say, the last 50 quicksaves. This would in my opinion remove the need to make "regular" saves.

Comment: @Vilx- Regular and quicksaves take no longer to make; it's how the engine treats them when *loading* that's different. i.e., it ignores a bunch of initialisation that it assumes it doesn't need to do and skips those parts of the file. Besides, it takes no longer to make regular saves as it takes to make quicksaves. You'd be better off taking the tack of the old Oblivion Streamline mod's [Streamsave](http://www.oblivionmodwiki.com/index.php/Streamline#Streamsave): a managed queue of full saves in a native mod. 'Sides, loading is less frequent than saving, so optimising it isn't actually useful.

Comment: Hmm... so, does that mean that the quicksave files have some kind of flag in them that mark them as "quicksaves" and thus alter the loader's behavior? Or is it just the filename?

Also - I've been using quicksaves practically exclusively in my game (over 80 hours of play now), and haven't seen any glitches because of it. How so then?

Comment: @Vilx Luck, perhaps? It's not that they're inherently broken, it's that they present another opportunity for bug interactions. Skyrim is less bad than Oblivion for quicksave-triggered bugs, yes. Go ahead and experiment with it if you're going to anyway—just keep this in mind should you ever run into problems.

Comment: Well, I do load *infrequently*. :) I guess that could be it. And loading when the game has just started up would be a full load, if I understand you correctly. So no problems with that. I wonder - do autosaves also fall in the same category as quickasves? I found a setting that increases the amount of autosaves (though haven't tested it yet) - maybe that could work for me.